# Unresolved reference: readln - in InteliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin

this code in a new project throws "Unresolved reference: readln" error

```
fun main() {
    val z = readln()
}
```

But on another project in Intelij IDEA works ok. Why so?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

`readln()` was added in Kotlin 1.6. Make sure you are using Kotlin 1.6 or later.

Answer (score 0):

The `readln` function is only available since version 1.6.0 of Kotlin, see it's [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/readln.html)

Most likely the other project uses an older version of Kotlin, in which this function was not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

thanks!

I had to go to Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin - and change Update channel from "Stable" to Early Access Preview 1.6.x or 1.7.x

Comment: Kotlin 1.6.10 is stable, not early access. Make sure your Kotlin plugin is up to date.